# Getting data out of JUnit test class in threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I am running some JUnit tests programatically with `JUnitCore`, and I want to get some data out of the test class once it is finished (so `@AfterClass`). Here is a pseudocode example of the constraints I am working under:

```
public class A {
    public static String testData;       

    public static void runTest() {
        JUnitCore juc = new JUnitCore();
        juc.run(B);

        // This is where I would like to access testData for this 
        // particular run
    }

    public static void setTestData(String s) {
        testData = s;
    }
}

public class B {
    // Some @Test methods and stuff omitted

    @AfterClass
    public static void done(String s) {
        A.setTestData(someData);
    }
}
```

My problem is that different threads might be calling `runTest()`, so `testData` might be wrong. How do I work around this? I'm so lost.

Comment: Does *runTest* only read the data? If so you should not have any issue, assuming *runTest* is launched after *done*.

Comment: @Pragmateek maybe my example wasn't the clearest, sorry. Basically runTest() is called which will in turn cause the methods in B to execute. If I understand JUnit correctly, runTest() will not complete until done() has completed. I want to get the data that done() sets, inside the runTest() method.

Comment: Why all your methods are static? If you need one context by run you'd better (if you can) use instances methods, so that each thread will work on its own set of local data. If all the threads need the same data you'll need some synchronization. Could you elaborate more on your scenario please?

Comment: I'm afraid that your example will never work. Probably, think about writing your own runner or use a singleton class to hold any data during testing time or look for some examples or best practicies about testing.

Comment: @MartinStrejc Okay thanks, I will look into a custom runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need/want to go with this design, you can make `testData` a `java.lang.ThreadLocal<String>`. This will solve the multi-threading issue.